# Summernote - Not able to see the mention list (generated dynamically in php) using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, summernote

Not able to see the mention list (user list is generated dynamically in php) and called using Ajax.
When type @ nothing displayed, my sample code is below -

```
hint: {
                
     match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
    mentions: function(keyword, callback) {
        //alert(keyword);
        $.ajax({
            url: "userMention.php?searchstr="+keyword,
                        
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            async: true
        }).done(callback);
        },
        search: function (keyword, callback) {
                    
            this.mentions(keyword, callback);
        },
        content: function (item) {
                    
           return '@' + item;
        }    
       },
```

From the above code example, I am not getting the list of mentions when type @User.
userMention.php returns user names i.e. ['User1','User2','User3'] (this list is dynamically fetched from database based on passed searchstr)